# styled-components 'css' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I have the following `Button.js`:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`

    background: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;

    ${props => props.add && css`
        background: palevioletred;
        color: white;
    `};

    ${props => props.delete && css`
        background: palevioletred;
        color: white;
    `};

`;

export default Button;
```

But when I run it I get the following error during compile:

> ./src/components/Button.js Line 10:  'css' is not defined  no-undef
>   Line 15:  'css' is not defined  no-undef

I then use the buttons like this:

```
<Button delete>Delete</Button>
<Button add>Add</Button>
```

Anything I did wrong here?

Comment: `props => props.add && css\`...\`` This is js. Variable `css` is not defined in this file. Maybe `styled.css\`...\``?

Comment: @BalázsÉdes that's what I also thought but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 19):

did you try to import css?

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
```

so your code should be

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`

    background: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;

    ${props => props.add && css`
        background: palevioletred;
        color: white;
    `};

    ${props => props.delete && css`
        background: palevioletred;
        color: white;
    `};

`;

export default Button;
```

Comment: It's amazing how their documentation doesn't mention that straight away, had to copy the example and find this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just import { css } up the top! This was mentioned before in a previous comment.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
//import './Button.css';

const Button = styled.button`
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: black;

  ${props =>
    props.primary &&
    css`
      backround: blue;
    `}
`;

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally "figured it out" by going:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`

    background: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;

    ${(props) => {
        if (props.add) {
            return 'background: green;'
        } else if (props.delete) {
            return 'background: red;'
        } else {
            return 'background: black;'
        }
    }}

`;

export default Button;
```

which worked... even though in my question above I followed the docs **exactly**.

Comment: You missed importing *css*