# I searched it on the Internet and it says how to make reusable components. I have a question

Tags: css, reactjs

I typed exactly what came out of the book, but it says css is not defined.
Is it because the content of the react has changed a lot? Or what's the problem?

```
   import React from "react";
   import styled from "styled-components";

   const StyledButton = styled.button`
       border: none;
       border-radius: 4px;
       font-size: 1rem;
       font-weight: bold;
       padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
       color: white;
       outline: none;
       cursor: pointer;

       background: #343a40;
       &:hover {
           background: #868e96;
       }

       ${(props) =>
           props.fullwidth &&
           css`
               padding-top: 0.75rem;
               padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
               width: 100%;
               font-size: 1.125rem;
            `}

       ${(props) =>
            props.cyan &&
            css`
                background: #3bc9db;
                &:hover {
                    background: #66d9e8;
                }
            `}
    `;

    const Button = (props) => <StyledButton {...props} />;

    export default Button;
```

```
[eslint]
src\components\common\button.js
  Line 21:9:  'css' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 30:9:  'css' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
ERROR in [eslint]
src\components\common\button.js
  Line 21:9:  'css' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 30:9:  'css' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I erased the css letter and looked up the literature, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Please edit your question so the title _is_ your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [styled-components 'css' is not defined no-undef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855700/styled-components-css-is-not-defined-no-undef)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `css` from the `styled-components` package, so the import will look like this:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
```

Comment: Wow, it's so simple.. You'll be blessed today..

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using CSS?

you can just remove it and it will work.

Comment: I put cyan and fullwidth prop in the button component, so I wrote it down because I heard a different style is applied, but can I just make it styled instead of like this?